# Invalid key for attachdb

Tags: c#, sql-server

My connection string is:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StockDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StockDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

It is showing:

> invalid key for attachDbfilename.

Comment: Is this a web application example you are following?

Comment: No, It is Window application

Answer (score 1):

`AttachDBFilename` is unique to SQL Express. If you are using SQL Express only then you will be able to use this key in connection string. If you are not using SQL Express then you will get this error. Use `database=` if it is not SQL Express.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\v11.0;Initial Catalog=StockDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\StockDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

**dot(.)** instead of (LocalDB)